# SailsJS Blueprints going haywire

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I had been working on an app using SailsJS v0.12. The app was working as expected. But, for some modules, it made sense to upgrade to v1.0 because it offered some great features, and the website implied (or seemed so) that the upgrade process was simple.

That wasn't the case. After a day of tedious refactoring, I succeeded in building the existing code and started working on the new modules. The problem to focus on began here.

I ran the functions as I did previously in *POSTman* and I stopped getting response. To check individual models, I tried using the Blueprints. Since no structural changes were made to any of the models, this should've worked. But I couldn't get any response in POST; GET was still working. I logged off for a break and then made a GET request to a model with some associations (working perfectly before).

I got this response

> UsageError: Invalid populate(s). Details:   Could not populate
>   `customer` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular ("model")
>   association, which means it never refers to more than *one* associated
>   record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to
>   `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it
>   generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks
>   like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) *was* provided! (Note
>   that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special
>   case that *does* make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future
>   version of Waterline.)
>
> Here's what was passed in: { limit: 30 }

The complete JSON response is:

```
{
    "stack": "UsageError: Invalid populate(s).\nDetails:\n  Could not populate `customer` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular (\"model\") association, which means it never refers to more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)\n\nHere's what was passed in:\n{ limit: 30 }\n\n    at findRecords (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\hooks\\blueprints\\actions\\find.js:40:21)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\router\\bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:164:37)\n    at param (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:167:11)\n    at alwaysAllow (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\hooks\\policies\\index.js:224:11)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\router\\bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:164:37)\n    at param (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:167:11)\n    at module.exports (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\hooks\\cors\\clear-headers.js:14:3)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\router\\bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:164:37)\n    at param (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:167:11)\n    at sails.router.bind._middlewareType (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\hooks\\csrf\\index.js:148:11)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\router\\bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:164:37)\n    at param (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:167:11)\n    at _addResViewMethod (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\hooks\\views\\res.view.js:372:3)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\sails\\lib\\router\\bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:164:37)\n    at param (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (D:\\Dev\\NodeJS\\zingr\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:100:7)",
    "message": "Invalid populate(s).\nDetails:\n  Could not populate `customer` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular (\"model\") association, which means it never refers to more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)\n\nHere's what was passed in:\n{ limit: 30 }\n",
    "name": "UsageError",
    "code": "E_INVALID_POPULATES",
    "details": "Could not populate `customer` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular (\"model\") association, which means it never refers to more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)\n\nHere's what was passed in:\n{ limit: 30 }"
}
```

The confusing aspect is that this is only happening locally. The blueprints work perfectly as expected on the deployment (same code, double-checked) hosted on Zeit.co. I have tested this enough times to deduce that this isn't a fault in my models. Nonetheless, here are the models - `Bill` and `Customer`:

**`models\Bill.js`**

```
module.exports = {

    primaryKey:'id',
    attributes: {
        createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
        updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },

        id:{
            type:'string',
            required:true
        },
        bill_number:{
            type:'string'
        },
        admin_id:{
            type:'string'
        },
        channel:{
            type:'string'
        },
        amount:{
            type:'number'
        },
        discount:{
            type:'number',
            defaultsTo:0
        },
        order_date:{
            type: 'number'
        },
        status:{
            type:'string',
            isIn:['generated', 'settled', 'canceled'],
            defaultsTo:'generated'
        },
        type:{
            type:'string',
            isIn:['dine-in', 'take-away', 'delivery', 'logistics-delivery'],
            required:true
        },
        logisticsPartner:{
            type:'string',
            defaultsTo:'phone'
        },

        //association
        customer:{
            model:'customer'
        },

        store:{
            model:'store'
        },
        orderContents:{
            collection:'billmapping',
            via:'bill'
        },
        transactions:{
            collection:'transaction',
            via:'bill'
        }
    }

};
```

**`models\Customer.js`**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
        updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },

        id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true}, // <-- for SQL databases
        name:{
            type:'string'
        },
        number:{
            type:'string',
            unique:true
        },
        email:{
            type:'string',
            unique:true
        },
        age:{
            type:'number'
        }
    }
};
```

This issue has had me pulling my hair out for 8 hours now. Can anybody shed some light or share some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved the issue by removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again. This is not a satisfactory explanation to the issue. Hence, I'm not putting this up as an answer.